# I need an idea of creating methods that take elements before it

Tags: javascript, methods, pure-js

**I need an idea of creating methods that take elements before it**

> note it should take a defined element instead of an object
>   example:

```
"use strict";
var element = document.getElementById('name').value;
elment.capitalize();//the capitaze should be a function
```

> i will appriciate for your help.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot use the `method` to get associated with a variable and invoke that. For that scenario we have objects to take care of. You can create a object data structure with necessary properties and functions so that when you call `capitalize()` function of that object you get the uppercase value of `name` property of that object.

```js
var element = {
 name: 'name',
 capitalize: function(){
   this.name = this.name.toUpperCase();
   return this.name;
 }
}

var name = element.capitalize();
console.log(name);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir!